# docker-compose.ymlでcronを実行したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron

Railsのwheneverを利用して、docker-compose.ymlの`command`でcronを実行後、ジョブの登録をしたいのですが、ジョブ登録コマンドの動作がうまくいかない状況です。

```
command: >
      bash -c "
      cron -f; # cron起動
      bundle exec whenever --update-crontab; # ジョブ登録
      "
```

`docker-compose up`時に、cron起動コマンドからジョブ登録コマンドまで一通りは実行されるものの、
`docker-compose exec railsコンテナのサービス名 bash`でbashに入り、登録されたジョブを確認（`crontab -l`）すると、何も登録されていないと表示されてしまいます。

```
no crontab for root
```

ただbashに入ってから、ジョブ登録コマンドを実行すると正常に登録されるのが不思議でわかりません。
一般的にDocker上でcronを扱うのは結構ネックのようですが、このやり方でもできないのでしょうか？

ご教示いただけると助かります。

Debian環境ですので、手動で行う分にはスケジューラー自体の動作は正常であることを確認しました。

## ソースコード

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  ruby_base:
    build: .
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/
    working_dir: /var/www/rails_api
    command: >
      bash -c "
      cron -f;
      bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
      "
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV TZ Asia/Tokyo
ENV LC_ALL=C

# 必要なパッケージ & スケジューラー & Railsインストール
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential cron
RUN gem install -v 5.2.4 rails --no-document

# プロジェクトディレクトリ名を変数化
ARG project_name="rails_api"

# Gemfileのインストール
WORKDIR /var/www/${project_name}
COPY /${project_name}/Gemfile Gemfile
COPY /${project_name}/Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
```

## 追記 （himenonさん） 2020/06/03

debian:busterをimageにして、railsとbusyboxを1つのコンテナとして起動しています。

main.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# 初期のディレクトリ場所がrootディレクトリにいるため、cdでrailsのディレクトリまで移動しています
cd /var/www/プロジェクト名/rails_api;
bundle exec rake testtask:タスク1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問に対する直接的な回答にはなりませんが、cronをdockerで利用するときにハマりがちなので別のやり方を紹介します。

dockerでcronを利用する場合、いろいろ[設定をする必要](https://serverfault.com/questions/924779/docker-cron-not-working)がありますが、
busyboxに含まれるcrondを利用すると比較的簡単にcronジョブを仕込むことができます。

この最小サンプル紹介します。

### ディレクトリ構成

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── crontab
├── docker-compose.yml
└── main.sh
```

#### Dockerfile

- `ruby:2.7.1`のBase Imageをたどると`debian:buster`にたどり着くので、これをベースファイルとしてDockerfileを組み立てます。
- `busybox crond --help`を実行するとオプションが確認できます。適宜指定してください。

```
FROM debian:buster
ENV TZ Asia/Tokyo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y busybox-static

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./main.sh /app/

CMD ["busybox", "crond", "-l", "8", "-L", "/dev/stderr", "-f"]
```

#### crontab

デバッグ用に1分毎に実行します

```
* * * * * /app/main.sh
```

#### docker-compose.yml

- crontabファイルをマウントすることで外部から実行時間を指定できるようにしています。
- `Dockerfile`内で`CMD`を指定しているので、もしdocker-compose.ymlで`command`指定したい場合は`Dockerfile`を編集してください。

```
version: '3'

services:
  busybox:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./crontab:/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

#### main.sh

- ※`chmod +x main.sh`を実行済み
- 質問にあるコマンドを例えばこのファイルに記述することも可能です。
- この例では日付を出力します。

```sh
#!/bin/sh
date
```

### 実行

docker-composeを利用する場合

```sh
docker-compose build   # Docker Image絵をビルド
docker-compose up -d   # docker-composeをdaemon化
docker-compose logs -f # ログ出力
```

dockerコマンドで実行する場合

```sh
docker build -t my-busybox:0.0.1 .
docker run -d --rm -v $(pwd)/crontab:/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root my-busybox:0.0.1
docker logs -f [container id]
```

### 参考

- https://packages.debian.org/ja/sid/busybox

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やはり、busyboxがベストなんですね。構築・実行はうまくいきました。
ただ、railsとの連携周りの理解が微妙で、main.shの中身が回りくどいような無理矢理書いたような感じになってしまいました。
質問欄に追記しましたが、このような書き方で良いのでしょうか？

Comment: Dockerfileで`main.sh`をコピーしている場所を `/var/www/プロジェクト名/rails_api` のように変更すると、`cd`コマンドを利用しなくても直接bundleが立たけるようになると思います。もしくは、crontabで `/app/main.sh` を指定してるところを実行したいスクリプトに書き換えるという手もあります。ここで示しているのは一般的な例なので、ディレクトリの場所とかは適宜変更しても問題ありません。

Comment: わかりました。様々な方法が考えられそうなので、調べながらやってみます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

> docker-compose up時に、cron起動コマンドからジョブ登録コマンドまで一通りは実行されるものの、

これはどのように確認しているのでしょうか．
ジョブ登録が正常に実行されないのは，`cron -f` がフォアグラウンド実行されているため後続の wheneverが実行されていないためです．

dockerコンテナ内でcronを起動するのがあまりよろしくないことを理解した上で実現したいのであれば，
コマンドの実行順序を逆にするだけで実現できます．
すなわち，docker-compose.ymlを以下のように修正します．

```
    command: >
      bash -c "
      bundle exec whenever --update-crontab；
      cron -f      
      "
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
エラーが発生しなかったため、実行されているものだと思っておりました。
フォアグラウンド起動で納得しました。
別の方法で検討してみたいと思います。